# If a realtor buys a home for themselves, do that still get paid the buyer's agent premium, or is all the commission kept by the listing agent?

Tags: united-states, real-estate

In my area, based on the Buyer Representation Agreement I have seen, Buyers Agents are paid from the listing agent ~2.5-3% of the sale price.

If an agent is looking to buy for themselves, is this fee still paid to them when they buy, or does this listing agent simply keep 100% of their commission?

Also if a private individual finds a property, and makes an offer to the listing agent directly, without retaining a buyers agent, would such a private individual be paid the ~2.5-3% premium mentioned in the main question?

Comment: For got to ask, if a private individual find a property, and make an offer to the listing agent directly, without retaining a buyers agent, would such a private individual be paid the ~2.5-3% premium mentioned in the main question.

Comment: I added the 2nd question.

Comment: I tagged it united-states because this question is nonsensical in other jurisdictions that don't work the same way. If it was actually intended to apply to another jurisdiction please comment or edit the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose it might vary by state, but in Massachusetts, a buyer can be their own agent and get the commission.

A friend of mine is an attorney, and in Massachusetts, it is trivial for an attorney to get a realtor's license (just pay a fee).  My friend got a realtor's license solely for the purpose of being his own buyer's agent and getting the commission.

A person who is not a realtor has no right to commission when they buy without an agent.  Though you could use that as a bargaining chip to get a discount on the price.